# Number of integer partitions modulo 3

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Motivated by [Parity of number of partitions of $n!/6$ and $n!/2$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323308), I asked my computer (and my FriCAS package for guessing) for an algebraic differential equation for the number of integer partitions modulo 3.  This is what it answered:

```
(1) -> s := [partition n for n in 1..]

   (1)  [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42, ...]
                                                        Type: Stream(Integer)
(32) -> guessADE([s.i for i in 1..400], safety==290, maxDerivative==2)$GUESSF PF 3

   (32)
   [
     [
         n
       [x ]f(x):
               3    2      2          ,,       4 ,   3       3          2  ,   2
             (x f(x)  + 2 x f(x) + x)f  (x) + x f (x)  + (2 x f(x) + 2 x )f (x)

           +
                            ,            2
             (2 x f(x) + 2)f (x) + 2 f(x)

         =
           0
       ,
                          3      4
      f(x) = 1 + 2 x + 2 x  + O(x )]
     ]
```

Of course, this is only a guess, but it seems fairly well tested.  Only 110 terms were needed to guess the recurrence, all the other 290 were used to check it.

My question is: is this known, and if not so, is this interesting?

Comment: I should add: for the parity of the partition function, no such differential equation was found - at least not using the first few hundred terms.

Comment: Would you please rewrite the same equation for $1/f=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{k(3k+1)/2}$? It looks on the first glance that the key property of 3 is that the derivative of $1/f$ has simplified (compared to other localisations) formula: $(2/f)'=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k k x^{k(3k+1)/2}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, indeed, this is quite remarkable.  The equation for $1/f$ is simply $f(x)^2 f^{''}(x) + xf'(x)^3 + 2f(x)f'(x)^2=0$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't verify your ADE. If $\,f(x) = a_0 + a_1\,x + O(x^2)\,$ then your differential operator produces $\,(2a_0^2+2a_1)+O(x).\,$ Your power series has $\,a_0=1, a_1=2\,$ which gives $\,6+O(x)\,$ by my calculations instead of $0$.

Comment: @Somos, I did not verify by hand, but your computation looks OK, since $6 + O(x) = O(x)\mod 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\,h(x) := \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - x^n)\,$ is known as a Ramanujan theta function. It is essentially the Dedekind $\eta$ function. The connection is $\,f(q) := q h(q^{24}) = \eta(24\tau)\,$ where $\,q=\exp(2\pi i \tau).\,$ Differentiating we get
$\, dq = (2\pi i)\, q\, d\tau,\,$ and
$$ \frac{d}{d\tau} f(q) = (2\pi i)\, q\, f'(q).$$
Since all powers of $\,q\,$ in $\,f(q)\,$ are of the form
 $\,q^{24n+1}\,$ then the congruence 
 $\,f'(q) - f(q) \equiv 0 \pmod 3\,$ holds.

If we use the original $\,h(x)\,$ then there is similar but more complicated result using modulo $3$ exponents. Let$\, A = A(x) := h(x)\,$ and let $\,A_0\,$ be all the terms of $\,A\,$ where the exponent of $\,x\,$ is $0$ modulo $3$ and similarly for $\,A_1\,$ and $\,A_2\,$ so that $\,A = A_0+A_1+A_2.\,$ This is the *trisection* of the power series $\,A.\,$ Refer to my essay [A Multisection of q-Series](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/multiq.html) for the nice identity
 $$ 0 = A_2 A_0^2 + A_0 A_1^2 + A_1 A_2^2. \tag{1}$$
Now let $\, B = B(x) := A'(x)\,$ and let $\,B_0,B_1,B_2\,$ be the trisection of $\,B.\,$
It is easy to show that 
$$ q\,B_0 \equiv A_1,\quad q\,B_1 \equiv -A_2,
\quad B_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$$
Now let $\, C = C(q) := A''(x)\,$ and let
$\,C_0,C_1,C_2\,$ be the trisection of $\,C.\,$
It is easy to show that
$$ q^2\,C_0 \equiv -A_2, \quad C_1 \equiv C_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$$
When we make these substitutions in the expression
$$ h''(x) h(x)^2 + x\, h'(x)^3 + 2\,h(x)h'(x)^2 \tag{2}$$
and reduce modulo $3$ we get the nice identity $(1)$.

Comment: Very interesting! Do other relations in your essay also produce differential equations modulo other primes?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Good question!! I had not considered differential equation power series modulo primes before which is why the original question confused me. However, based on my experience with other kinds of congruences between power series I would not be surprised. For example, $ \theta_3^4(q) = \theta_4^4(q) + \theta_2^4(q)$ and $\theta_2^4(q) \equiv 0 \pmod {16}$

Comment: as I understood from OP, there are difficulties already with differential equation modulo 2. On the other hand, it may appear, say, that there exists a non-trivial relation modulo 4 which is trivial modulo 2.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I am not surprised at the modulo 2 problem. It has to do with modular functions I think. You may be correct about modulo 4 though. I am not sure.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Okay, I got some modulo 8 results. Let $f:=f(x), f_1:=f'(x), f_2:=f''(x),f_3:=f'''(x).$ Then $6 f f_1^3 +3f^2 f_1 f_2 + 3 f^3 f_3 + 2x f_1^4 + x f^2 f_2^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$  based on a 4th degree 4-section identity.

Comment: Unfortunately, my package requires that the coefficients live in a field.  However, I checked all primes below $20$, and found equations for all of them with the exception of the prime $2$.  I guess that for larger primes the differential equation in https://mathoverflow.net/a/47706 should be non-degenerate.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $f''f^2 +xf' ^3+2ff'^2 =0$ modulo 3 for $f=\prod(1-x^m)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z} } (-1)^nx^{n(3n+1)/2}$ may be quickly seen as follows.

Differentiating the power series for $f$ and expanding the brackets we see that we should prove that
$$
\sum_{a(3a+1)/2+b(3b+1)/2+c(3c+1)/2=n} 
(-1)^{a+b+c} \left(a(a-2)-abc+2ab\right) 
$$
is divisible by 3. Multiplying the sum by 3 and using cycling shift of variables we reduce it to proving that the sum
$$
\sum_{a(3a+1)/2+b(3b+1)/2+c(3c+1)/2=n} 
(-1)^{a+b+c} \left( a(a-2)+b(b-2)+c(c-2)-3abc+2ab+2bc+2ac\right) 
$$
is divisible by 9.

The summand is $(a+b+c) (a+b+c-2)-3abc$. If $a=b=c$ this is $9a^2 - 3(a^3+2a)$, divisible by 9. Other triples partition by permuting the variables onto 3-tuples and 6-tuples, so the sum of $3abc$ is of course divisible by 9. As for $a+b+c$, it is congruent to $2n$ modulo 3, thus unless $n=3t+2$ the expression $(a+b+c) (a+b+c-2)$ is divisible by 3, as we need.

It remains to show that for $n=3m+2$ the sum of $(-1)^{a+b+c}$ over our triples is divisible by 9. In other words, the coefficient of $x^{3m+2} $ in $f^3$ must be divisible by 9. We have 
$$
f^3=\prod (1-x^k)^3 =\prod (1-x^{3k}+3(x^k-x^{2k})).
$$
Expanding the brackets and reducing modulo 9 we should prove that the expression
$$
[x^{3m+2} ] 3 f(x^3) \sum_k \frac{x^k-x^{2k} } {1 - x^{3k} }
$$
is divisible by 9.
But in the latter sum $\sum_k (x^k-x^{2k}+x^{4k}-x^{5k}+\dots) $ all coefficients of powers $x^{3s+2} $ do cancel, since if $3s+2=kr$, the guys $x^{kr} $ and $x^{rk} $ go with different signs.

Comment: Very very nice!  Although I must say that it doesn't answer the question :-)